# A strange, empty square originated from facebook

Tags: facebook, api, frame

I hope I can find an answer to my question on this forum. We run a Joomla site (v1.5.23) and have integrated facebook comments, recommendations etc on the site.

A while ago a strange squared frame turned up on our site. If I check the frames code I can see that it is originated from Facebook (there are for example references to s-static.ak.fbcdn.net).

I can't find out why this is shown like this. I have tried to unpublish the facebook-plugins in Joomla, but it is still there.

Does someone have an idea what this can be and how I can get rid of it?

Here are a live page, search for "Det är förmiddag, lätt nattfrost, ett svagt ljus" - in that paragraph you will see the frame:

http://www.tidningenkulturen.se/artiklar/ess-mainmenu-57/riga-mainmenu-130/11840-mjaellare-aen-aelfvenben

Or here is an image of it: http://my.jetscreenshot.com/5366/20120412-kw0j-300kb

With kind regards,
 - Johan.

Comment: Those erroneous iframes have the following inline styles: `<div style="position: absolute; top: -2000px; ">`. If you haven't set that, maybe the FB javascript is bugging out due to the other JS errors on your page

Answer (score 0):

welcome to stackoverflow!

Add the following to your CSS stylesheet and it will go away. After you do it, just check that it doesn't hide anything that you don't want hidden.

```
iframe#fb_xdm_frame_http {display:none;}
iframe#fb_xdm_frame_https {display:none;}
```

If this helped you, please consider supporting http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34294/joomla-answers

Cheers!